# Accuracy Rate with Timing

Tags: statistics

I have a test that my students take where I am interested in both their accuracy rate as well as the speed in which it took them to complete the test.

The results look like this:

> Bob: 56/66 400s
>
> Jan: 60/66 320s

I want to generate an accuracy rate as represented in seconds. In other words, I want the rate to mean: "It took Bob 5.6s per **correct** answer."

How do I do this as it appears to be more than a simple division of the time/raw-result?